# How can i add sample data to an edmx file and display it in Visual-Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, xsd, entity-framework-5

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and ADO.Net Entity Data Model to create my database schema. Since i am still drafting and discussing the schema i would like to be able to add example data to the edmx-file and be able to show it in the designer like in the following screenshot:

[image: How to display data-model plus sample-data in Visual Studio]

### Source code of EDMX file with added sample data

The underlying xml-code would contain the normal edmx-output and on top the sample data like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
....
<EntityType Name="Title">
  <Documentation>
    <Summary>Table titles contains all the dvd-title we have in our store</Summary>
  </Documentation>
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
  </Key>
  <Property Type="Int32" 
          Name="Id" Nullable="false" 
          annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
  <Property Type="String" Name="Title" Nullable="false" >
  <Documentation>
    <Summary>The title of the movie</Summary>
    <LongDescription>
         The translated title of the movie and the original title     
    </LongDescription>
  </Documentation>
 </Property>
</EntityType>
<Titles>
    <Title>  
        <id>810</id>
        <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
        <year>1994</year>
    </Title> 
    <Title>  
        <id>940</id>
        <title>Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels</title>
        <year>1998</year>
    </Title> 
</Titles>
```

The sample data should be displayed and should be editable in design view.

**Does anyone know a tool or a way to combine the edmx-file and to display and add sample data?**

Bonus Question: When i generate the sql-statement the documentation is not added to the sql statement. Is there a way to include the documentation of the fields and the tables so that they would be added to Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. One of the reasons is that what you see is a model and not the database schema. What you don't see is how entity is mapped to the database. In the basic scenario there is 1:1 mapping indeed but once you start customizing your model you may end up having columns in the database with names different from the property names in the model, you may have complex properties you would not even have corresponding properties for on the diagram, you may put multiple entities to one table or one entity to multiple tables. How are you going to show this? And since it is just entity model and not table model data does not seem to be a good fit. I don't know of any tool that could do what you need. Edmx is an Xml file and the designer itself is extensible and based on DSL. You can try cooking something yourself but it will be a lot of work.